# change direction of nav items

Tags: html, css

Been trying to reverse navbar which includes a logo, nav items, and social icons ( left to right) so that it will be right to left.
i have used float:right and also direction:rtl 
However, the logo remains on right as it is, nav items changes direction from right left, social icons also changes to right to left, but the div that contains social icon remain left.

What I want to achieve is: flip nav bar so that it will be logo, nav items, social icons (right to left).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="../images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 " >
            <nav class="mainNav2">
                <div class="mobileMenu2">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <ul >
                    <li class="has-menu-items">ABOUT US
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>HISTORY</li>
                            <li>ORGANIZATION</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="has-menu-items">MEDIA
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>PHOTO GALLERY</li>
                            <li>VIDEOS</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="has-menu-items">DOWNLOADS</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="socialIcon">
                <a class="fb" href="#" title="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a class="ig" href="https://www.instagram.com/ title="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled a bit with understanding your question, however the easiest way to align items is to use a flexbox, i suggest you take a look at this link:

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Also this is the result i got which can easily be exapanded on

[image]

your html has alot of unnecessary divs and classes, it would be easier if you named the classes accordingly.

```css
/*logo, nav items, social icons*/
a {
  color: lime;
}

.container {
  background: #333;
  color: white;


  display: flex;

  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

.logo {
  border: 2px solid cyan;

}

.navItems {
  border: 2px solid lime;
  
}

.socialIcon {
  border: 2px solid yellow;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">

<div class="container">


            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">IMG HERE</a>
            </div>

        <div class="navItems">

                  <div class="mobileMenu2">
                      <span></span>
                      <span></span>
                      <span></span>
                  </div>
                    <ul >
                        <li class="has-menu-items">ABOUT US
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li>HISTORY</li>
                                <li>ORGANIZATION</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-menu-items">MEDIA
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li>PHOTO GALLERY</li>
                                <li>VIDEOS</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-menu-items">DOWNLOADS</li>
                    </ul>
      </div>


            <div class="socialIcon">
                <a class="fb" href="#" title="facebook">FB LOGO HERE</a>
                <a class="ig" href="https://www.instagram.com/ title="instagram">IG LOGO HERE</a>
            </div>
    </div>

</html>
```